# Receiving "Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed." error when I run my code?

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app for a class project. Very new to Shiny and somewhat new to R. My code is sampled below.  the data set I am using is attached it is a Covid-19 dataset [opensource](https://www.kaggle.com/terenceshin/covid19s-impact-on-airport-traffic) in this hyperlink. I am trying to get charts to show for each airport by their percentage baseline over time. Can anyone help with the error I am receiving when I run it

> Error in `$.shinyoutput`(output, plot) : Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed."?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#build plot

ui <- fluidPage(
      
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Airlines affected by COVID-19"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("airport", "Select an Aiport",
                        "Names",
                        selectize = TRUE)
        )
    ,
        mainPanel(
         plotOutput("plot")
     )
)
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

    data <- reactive({
       
        req(input$airport)
         
        df <- COVIDAIR %>% filter(AirportName %in% input$airport) %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarize(PercentOfBaseline = mean(PercentOfBaseline))
  })
    
    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, "airport", choices = COVIDAIR$AirportName)
    })
    
    
      
     output$plot({   
       g <- ggplot(data(), aes(y = PercentOfBaseline, x = Date))
       g + geom_line(stat = "mean")    
    
     })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `output$plot({ })` doesn't make sense. You'd want to do `output$plot <- renderPlot({ ... })`. Also, you need to remove `df <-` in the creation of your `data()` reactive object. Finally, I'm not understanding the purpose of `updateSelectInput() here`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out by @Phil there are few mistakes in your code. Apart from that -

- It is better to change `Date` to date class so that you can use  `scale_x_date` to format the dates.
- Pass dropdown options in `selectInput` itself since that is not going to change.

```
library(shiny)

COVIDAIR$Date <- as.Date(COVIDAIR$Date)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Airlines affected by COVID-19"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("airport", "Select an Aiport",
                  "Names",
                  selectize = TRUE, choices = unique(COVIDAIR$AirportName))
    )
    ,
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$airport)
    COVIDAIR %>% 
      filter(AirportName %in% input$airport) %>% 
      group_by(Date) %>% 
      summarize(PercentOfBaseline = mean(PercentOfBaseline))
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({   
    ggplot(data(), aes(y = PercentOfBaseline, x = Date, group = 1)) + 
    geom_line() + scale_x_date(breaks = '1 month')
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Okay that worked. The reason I was doing updateselectinput was because it was not working for me earlier when I ran choices = unique(COVIDAIR$AirportName). I learned about the "Names" argument you added in a video. But can you please explain why you used it here? and why did geom_line() not need an argument?

Comment: Ohh..the "Names" argument I copied it from your code as it is. I think it is not needed. We don't need any argument in `geom_line` because we have already calculated `mean` value in `reactive` function.

Comment: I have now updated my code to have three panels I would like to show. The same as the airport data but now grouped by country? And then a simple summary page table with all the airports. I tried implementing this and was able to create the tabs but cannot get the charts to go with out breaking. any tips? also thanks so  much for your help thus far!

Comment: @RJayne Please don't update/change your question after it has been answered. Ask only 1 specific question per post. If you have additional questions please ask that as a new question.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to this website and am still learning about the community. I will not do that in the future.